# Sort a list of python objects based on a local vairable

Tags: python, class, sorting

I need to sort a list of python objects by a local variable.

For example I have a list of objects of class item;

```
class item():
    nummber1 = random.randInt(0, 100)
    nummber2 = random.randInt(0, 100)

listOfObjects = []
for i in range(0, 20)
    listOfObjects.append(item())
```

However, now I have that list I need to sort it based on the number1 local variable...

I have tried:

```
listOfObjects = listOfObjects.sort()
```

However, this doesnt seam to sort by either number1 or number2 local variable... I'm actually not sure what the list is being sorted by...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `key` function like so:

```
listOfObjects = sorted(listOfObjects, key=lambda item: item.number1)
```

Comment: This won't work. This would sort a number of different `item` objects based on the value of their `number1` attribute. We're talking about sorting `number1` through `numberN` _within_ the `item` class.

Comment: then generate a tuple! key=lambda item: item.number1, item.number2, ... item.numberN. Tuples support itemwise comparisson

Comment: Maybe I misread OP's question actually. This is a really confusing class :P

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
listOfObjects.sort(key=lambda x: x.number1)
```

The `.sort` will return None and will sort in place

Answer (score 0):

There are few small problems in your code. But the answer to your question is that you can use `sorted` to which you can provide the key to be used to compare the items in the list.

```
import random

class item():
    def __init__(self):
        self.number1 = random.randint(0, 100)
        self.number2 = random.randint(0, 100)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[" + str(self.number1) + ", " + str(self.number2) + "]"

def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()

listOfObjects = []
for i in range(0, 20):
    listOfObjects.append(item())

def getKey(item):
    return item.number1

print(sorted(listOfObjects, key=getKey))
```

Sample output:

```
[[3, 18], [12, 11], [12, 17], [25, 41], [32, 48], [37, 1], [44, 85], [49, 39], [53, 11], [63, 57], [67, 0], [69, 34], [70, 23], [78, 25], [78, 17], [80, 87], [85, 70], [87, 29], [95, 28], [96, 44]]
```